# Changing tld_list_add function

Tags: c, binary-tree

Is there any way to shorten this portion of the code? For this add function. Having some difficulties. Basically I want to do a list that generates the TLD of domains and display it according to how user input the dates. but I feel my code is rather lengthy and I wish to cut short it. This is one of the function I wish to shorten it.

```
int tldlist_add(TLDList *tld, char *hostname, Date *d) {
    // check if it's within the tld dates
    if (date_compare(tld->begin, d) > 0 ||
            date_compare(tld->end, d) < 0)
        return 0;

    // capture the actual tld
    char *tld_start = strrchr(hostname, '.') + 1;
    int tld_len = strlen(tld_start);
    char *tld_s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (tld_len + 1));
    tld_s[tld_len] = '\0'; // make sure there is a null end
    strcpy(tld_s, tld_start);

    if (tld->root == NULL) {
        // list is empty, just add to root
        TLDNode *node = tldnode_create(tld_s);
        node->count++;
        tld->root = node;
        tld->size++; // new node
    } else {
        // add to list. do we need to free the string?
        if (!tldlist_add_r(tld, tld_s, tld->root))
            free(tld_s);
        else {
            tld->size++; // new node, so increase size

            // we must now rebalance the tree
            tldlist_rebalance(tld);
        }
    }

    tld->count++;
    return 1; // maximum success
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a particularly long and involved function to me. Why do you want to shorten it? Is there a performance concern, or just number of source code lines?

Comment: I need help in understanding this code, why must we do a count plus to the overall malloc?

Comment: The code you present is not complete, and there is no real question. `malloc` allocates space for the string represetation of the TLD (e.g. ".com"), and has nothing to do with the counter variable `count` in `TLDNode` as far as I can see. Start with a basic C tutorial and go from there.

Comment: But i have to iterate through a binary tree and do a counter+ for it? what other code do u guys still need? im a bit confused by this code

Comment: Why am i getting a syntax error: missing ';' before 'type'                  for this code: char *tld_start = strrchr(hostname, '.') + 1;